# Как вывести данные из БД на страницу WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Везде пишут что для обращения к таблицам БД в WordPress надо использовать $wpdb, но нигде не пишут куда его надо прописывать. В редакторе страниц PHP не распознаётся.

Прочитал что все манипуляции проводятся в файле functions.php шаблона, но в нём нет указаний на страницы, и файлов страниц я не нашёл. Куда писать этот $wpdb?

Comment: В любом шаблоне можете писать, но нужно ли оно?

Comment: @WPPunk Так как это работает? У меня есть страница и запись в таблице, как запись вывести на страницу?

Comment: Если вы про запись в смысле пост, то get_post( ID поста )

Comment: @WPPunk так а прописывать то куда это? И запись в смысле просто какие нибудь данные из таблички. Есть пустая страница, как вывести на неё данные из таблицы?

Comment: Тебе не надо использовать wpdb. Рано ещё. Очень рано. Лучше создай отдельный вопрос с описанием чего надо решить.  Предварительно ознакомься с https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy

Comment: @SeVlad какой принцип работы у WordPress? Ну вот насоздавал я разделов и пустых страниц, как на страницы вывести что то? В ручную всё вводить?

Comment: Принцип такой же как и любой другой CMS CMS- это система управления контентом. КОНТЕНТОМ, а не файлами. Не нужно создавать пустых страниц - эта сущность должна содержать контент.

Answer (score 1):

$wpdb - это глобальная переменная для запроса к базе данных

Что бы её использовать нужно предварительно подключить глобальную переменную

`global $wpdb;`

после чего можешь писать запрос

Пример запроса:

```
$newtable = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id FROM newtable" );
```

Писать запрос можешь в любом php файле темы или плагина

Comment: нужно же как то указать на какую страницу я хочу вывести результаты запроса к БД, как это сделать?

Comment: @Artyom Я могу Вам помочь если более подробнее опишите задачу, приложите ссылку или скриншот куда именно вы бы хотели вывести результат запроса.

Comment: я делаю учебный проект, пока просто создал тестовую страницу и таблицу с парой записей, пытался их вывести на эту страницу но не понял как

Comment: @Artyom уже лучше, если вы хотите вывести результат на страницу то можете воспользоваться шаблоном для страниц, или воспользоваться файлом page.php который лежит в корне вашей темы.

Comment: в page.php никаких указаний на конкретные страницы а в меню создания/редактирования страницы негде php код вставлять

Comment: Если вы хотите вывести на конкретную одну страницу скопируйте файл page.php  название-страницы.php в него добавьте следующие строки
`/**
* Template Name: Название страницы`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107683/discussion-between---and-artyom).

Comment: Напрасно ты это затеял. ТС не понимает что такое движок в принципе.

Comment: @SeVlad так в чём суть движка?

Comment: @Artyom я тебе выше объяснил. + https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC